# Updating SQL Server data from Excel, best practice?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

My requirement is to allow the direct editing of SQL Server tables from Excel. Just updates, not deletions or insertions.

My current solution is to load the data into an Excel worksheet with the builtin OLE DB connection tool. And then use the below code to capture worksheet changes on the table, and execute SQL commands through an ADODB connection.

[It is essentially a paired down version of [this](https://www.excel-sql-server.com/excel-sql-server-import-export-using-vba.htm) from 2011.]

Is this best practice? Or is there some better way to achieve the same result?

```vb
Public oldValue As Variant

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Or IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub
oldValue = Target.Value

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim KeyCells As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim SQLTable As String
Dim ID_Name As String
Dim ID_Value As String
Dim Field_Name As String
Dim Field_Value As String
Dim store As Variant
Dim reset As Integer

Set KeyCells = ListObjects("Table1").Range
If Intersect(Target, KeyCells) Is Nothing Or Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

SQLTable = "[dbo].[My_Table]"
ID_Name = ListObjects("Table1").HeaderRowRange(1).Value
ID_Value = Cells(Target.Row, 1).Value
Field_Name = ListObjects("Table1").HeaderRowRange(Target.Column).Value
Field_Value = Target.Value


Call SqlUpdate(SQLTable, ID_Name, ID_Value, Field_Name, Field_Value, 0, reset)


End Sub



Sub SqlUpdate(SQLTable As String, ID_Name As String, ID_Value As String, Field_Name As String, Field_Value As String, Confirm As Integer, ByRef reset As Integer)

Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Dim sConnString As String
Dim SQLCommand As String
Dim iCols As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim server As String
Dim DataBase As String

server = "My_server"
DataBase = "My_databaase"

' Create the connection string.
sConnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=" & server & ";" & _
              "Initial Catalog=" & DataBase & ";" & _
              "Integrated Security=SSPI;"


' Create and Open the Connection.
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.Open sConnString

' Execute
SQLCommand = "update " & SQLTable & " set " & Field_Name & " = '" & Field_Value & "' where " & ID_Name & " = '" & ID_Value & "';"

On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
    Set rs = conn.Execute(SQLCommand, RecordsAffected:=i)

    ' Clean up
    If CBool(conn.State And adStateOpen) Then conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing
    reset = 0
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
reset = 1
MsgBox "Invalid Value: Table not updated."

End Sub
```

Comment: Don't write your own code, use SSIS to load the data into a staging table, update the target table. This will be several orders of magnitued faster than this code

Comment: Assuming an ADODB operation is needed, best practice would be to use a parameterized `ADODB.Command` and a command string with `?` placeholders instead of single quotes and concatenated values. That said, when you have working code and a question like "does this code adhere to best practices and can it be improved in any way?", your go-to destination is [codereview.se], not Stack Overflow ;-)

Comment: This code will actually *fail* if any field contains even a single `'`. That's the best case. Worst case, someone could enter something malicious, like `'; drop table users;--`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos correct. That's why a parameterized command is the way to go.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos could you further explain your comment about using SSIS and a staging table?

Comment: @egoburnswell this code is *nothing* like the original. It's not paired down, it's completely different. The original did *not* use raw SQL, it didn't suffer from SQL injection. It used ADO Recordsets and performed updates in batches. Perhaps you should read it again, understand what it does and only then modify it, *if* it requires any modification. Most likely it *doesn't*. If you don't want to add or delete just remove the lines that add or delete rows to the recordset. The rest are perfectly OK